# SPFX Extensions FieldCustomizers onRenderCell not called when redirect to folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I'm following this tutorial https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer
I successfully implemented the Percentage FieldCustomizer

However I found some issue when I tried to navigate within the Document Library.
Steps to replicate :

- Follow the article, deploy the spfx, and create following structure in the document library
  -ROOT
  --FolderA
  ---ItemA1
  --ItemB
  --ItemC
- ItemB and ItemC rendered properly
- Navigate into FolderA, ItemA1 **will not rendered properly**, I check from console.log, it seems the onRenderCell function still watching the root folder.
- Use the list breadcrumb, click on Root folder, **It will not redirect to root folder**, instead will throw **console error** regarding knockout js and stuck on the folder.
- refresh the page, and ItemA1 will be rendered correctly, and able to navigate to root folder using the breadcrumb.

Is this SPFX Extensions bug? Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by raising Microsoft support ticket.

The issue is related to the dispose object failure within knockout.js. The knockout.js is a symptom. The main issue is related to the react.js failed to unmount Component object lead to object render failure.

Microsoft team have enhanced the Field Customer rendering as well. We don’t need to click the item to show up the column. It will display automatically.